# Code Golfing Split String in Bash

Tags: code-golf, tips, bash

Let us play a little golfing game. 
Given a single line of N space separated numbers from STDIN, one must output those numbers on N lines.

So far, I came up with the three following bash solutions :

- `xargs -n1` (9)
- `tr \ \\n` (8)
- `fmt -1` (6)

Can anyone do better? I am eager to learn new tricks

Comment: It is frowned upon to limit the language.

Comment: It is also frowned upon to restrict the format of the input and the output.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG. You should perhaps change this to a `tips` question.

Comment: in bash, I think the minimum is 5, because you will have at least 2 chars for a command (single-char commands are not a thing IMO), a space, and at least 2 chars for an arg. And so I think, you are already 1st in line with `fmt -1`.

Comment: Can the space-separated numbers be input as a string (enclosed with quote symbols)? Can the output lines contain leading spaces with the numbers right-aligned? Can we use functions that take a string and output a string with newlines?

Comment: Can I get the the numbers from program arguments? In Tcl: `puts [join $argv \n]` — [demo](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_tcl_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMeVlObWcxMkJLc3c)

Comment: Your `tr` command needs an extra space: `tr \␣␣\\n` (9), not `tr \␣\\n` (8).

Comment: @V.Courtois 1-byte commands are definitely a thing, and, well, hypothetically, a 1-byte command can do the job...

Comment: @ErikTheOutgolfer oh okay, sorry then

Comment: bash or shell? all these are shell commands - not part of bash language.

Answer (score 0):

Bash (22)

```
read X;printf %d\\n $X  (thanks to manatwork but without literal NL)
```

`30 read -aX;printf "%d\n" ${X[*]}
26 read X;echo -e ${X// /\n}
28 printf "%d\n" $(</dev/stdin)
27 printf "%d\n" $(</dev/fd/0)
26 printf %d\n $(</dev/fd/0)
23 read X;printf "%d\n" $X`

Comment: As it says the input will contain just 1 line of numbers, `read X;printf '%d␤' $X` is enough. (Where ␤ is a literal line break.)